# How add derived class property EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm doing a migration and I don't see the property from the inheritor class.
I have next model. In class SomeClass i have virtual property which is correctly displayed, but when inheriting in the class, nothing is show

```
    public class School
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; init; }
       
        [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
        public SomeClass Parameter1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomeClass
    {
        public virtual ParameterTypes Type { get; }
    }

    public enum ParameterTypes
    {
        None,
        
        Value
    }
    
    
    public class DerivedClass : SomeClass
    {
        public override ParameterTypes Type => ParameterTypes.Value;
        
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

and i am add configure this model

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<School>(
            builder =>
            {
                builder.HasKey(h => h.Id);
                builder.Property(h => h.Parameter1).HasJsonConversion();
            });
    }
    
    public static PropertyBuilder<T> HasJsonConversion<T>(this PropertyBuilder<T> propertyBuilder)
            where T : class, new()
    {
        var converter = new ValueConverter<T, string>(
            v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, null),
            v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(v, null) ?? new T());

        var comparer = new ValueComparer<T>(
            (l, r) => JsonSerializer.Serialize(l, null) == JsonSerializer.Serialize(r, null),
            v => v == null ? 0 : JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, null).GetHashCode(),
            v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, null), null)
        );

        propertyBuilder.HasConversion(converter);
        propertyBuilder.Metadata.SetValueConverter(converter);
        propertyBuilder.Metadata.SetValueComparer(comparer);
        propertyBuilder.HasColumnType("jsonb");

        return propertyBuilder;
    }
```

when I do a migration, I see enum as a string (right), but I don’t see the property `DerivedClass.Value`

maybe the problem is in the HasJsonConversion method?

how to get property from inherited class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var converter = new ValueConverter<T, string>(
     v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, **v.GetType()**, jsonSerializerOptions),
     v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(v, jsonSerializerOptions));
```